# 2D-array display error

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, multidimensional-array

How am I supposed to display my 2D array? Or the average sum of my array? It won't let me.

The code is supposed to display a 2D array, add all those numbers, calculate the average and display the average.

```
// It gives me a richTextBox error. I tried to change 'float' to 'void' - gives
// me a return error.
//
// It says the object require non static field?
richTextBox1.AppendText(array[ i, j] + " ");
richTextBox1.AppendText(" "+ sum.ToString());
return avg; // <<< Error here

static float Avg(int[,] array)
{
    return (float)array.OfType<int>().Average();
    richTextBox1.Clear(); // <<<<==================== Here
    Random rand = new Random();
    float sum = 0;
    int rows = array.GetLength(0);
    int cols = array.GetLength(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            int value = rand.Next(-100, 100);
            array[i, j] = value;
            richTextBox1.AppendText(value + " "); // <<<<<<<===== Here
            if (value <= 0)
                sum += value;
            float avg = sum / value;
        }
        return avg;//<<<========here
    }
    richTextBox1.AppendText(" Total Average is: " + avg.ToString()); // <<<==== Here
}

private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Avg(A);
}
```

Comment: can you removfe the `static` property in your object?

Comment: I deleted the static now I got a float >>Avg<<< error could not return all paths?

Comment: Can you please show your complete program?

Comment: @shree.pat18 update it thats pretty much all

Comment: Please us the complete methods.

Comment: @MartinMulder There it is sorry about that

Comment: @TheBoringGuy The lines at the top of the code - where are they located? Also, why are you returning `avg` there? Where is `avg` decalred/defined?

Comment: @shree.pat18 updated pointed them out avg should be the average of the total sum

Comment: @TheBoringGuy `return avg; //<<< error here` -> Where is this line located in your code? In another method? In `main` method?

Comment: @shree.pat18 that is located 4-5 lines under the if statement. The main method is the very bottom where it says (private void)

Comment: how many times you will add same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23005641/2d-array-displaying-caculation-error

Comment: I deleted it but i guess deleting stuff dont work lol anywho thanks for the poeple who tried to help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
static float Avg(int[,] array)
{
   return (float)array.OfType<int>().Average();
}
```

Then you use it like this:

```
var array = new int [2,3] {{1,2, 3}, {4,5, 6}};
Console.WriteLine(Avg(array));
```

**Update - for jagged arrays**

```
static float Avg(int[][] array)
{
   return (float)array.SelectMany(a => a).Average();
}

void Main()
{
     int[][] array = 
    {
        new int[] {1,2,3},
        new int[] {4,5}
    };
    Console.WriteLine(Avg(array));
}
```

**Update 2**
if you want to do it your way try this:

```
    private void Avg(int [,] array)
{   
    richTextBox1.Clear();

    float sum = 0;
    int rows = array.GetLength(0);
    int cols = array.GetLength(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {                
            richTextBox1.AppendText(array[i,j] + " ");                
            sum += array[i,j];
        }
    }

    richTextBox1.AppendText(" Total Average is: " + (float)sum/(rows*cols));
}
```

Comment: that doesnt seem no do anything XD

Comment: But his array is not jagged, `int[,]` not `int [][]`

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I meant: does it work on multidimensional arrays?

Comment: It will work for multidimensional arrays, but not for jagged ones.

Comment: @NedStoyanov Is there a way I can do something with my code? you way I havent learned yet also I am using windows app form.

Comment: You sir are indeed my hero !

Answer (score 0):

Because we do not really know, what do you try to make with the Avg method. I just try to sumarize:

1. `static float Avg`: you cannot use `static` where you use Form instance members (like richTextBox1). Please remove 'static' or move usage of richTextBox1 just in the OnClick method.
2. Don't use `return` where you want. Everything after it will not process (if not using try/finally). If you want to use the returned value, call it on the last line after everything in method processed.
3. `return avg`: `avg` is not known in the current context, whether is defined in the previous closure (do you know what have your neighbour behind the closed doors?)

For the final solution, refer to Ned's answer.